# Renamespacing c++ header with perl - multiline issues

Tags: regex, perl, recursive-regex

I am trying to enclose the namespace of a c++ header-only library in a custom namespace to avoid symbol name collisions with customer code.

Here is the perl script i wrote. It should enclose the def namespace in the abc namespace.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) { 
    s/namespace\s+def\s*
    ( # group 1 - braced string with balanced number of lbraces and rbraces
        \{
        ( # group 2 - String without braces or recursion to group 1
            [^\{\}]* # some string that does not contain braces
            | (?1) # recursion of group1
        )*
        \}
    )
    /namespace abc {\nnamespace def \1\n}/gcsx;
    print;
}
```

and here is the testfile i am using:

```
namespace def {}
namespace def { abc }
namespace def { { } }
namespace def { { abcd } }
namespace def {
    abc
}
namespace def { // some comment
    do_something();
}
namespace def {
    do_something();
    while (still_not_crashed()) {
        do_even_more();
    }
}
```

however running the script on the file only yields

```
namespace abc {
namespace def {}
}
namespace abc {
namespace def { abc }
}
namespace abc {
namespace def { { } }
}
namespace abc {
namespace def { { abcd } }
}
namespace def {
    abc
}
namespace def { // some comment
    do_something();
}
namespace def {
    do_something();
    while (still_not_crashed()) {
        do_even_more();
    }
}
```

The one line namespace work just fine but as soon as the pattern that should be matched contains a newline it stops working eventhough i added the *s*-modifier to my regex.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: So your C++ question is how to debug your perl script?

Comment: I added the tag C++ because i think that some cpp devs may have encountered similar situations. It is mainly a perl question though.

Comment: You're doing the substitution line by line, so it doesn't work on multiline.

Comment: "Zero or more" of anything will always match, so `[^\{\}]*` always matches and the recursion is never executed. Also, the `/s` snd `/c` modifiers are ineffective here and should be omitted, and you should use `$1` instead of `\1` in the replacement string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to read the whole file in a string then do the substitution on this string:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

undef$/;
$_ = <DATA>;
    s/namespace\s+def\s*
    ( # group 1 - braced string with balanced number of lbraces and rbraces
        \{
        ( # group 2 - String without braces or recursion to group 1
            [^\{\}]* # some string that does not contain braces
            | (?1) # recursion of group1
        )*
        \}
    )
    /namespace abc {\nnamespace def $1\n}/gsx;
    print;


__DATA__
namespace def {}
namespace def { abc }
namespace def { { } }
namespace def { { abcd } }
namespace def {
    abc
}
namespace def { // some comment
    do_something();
}
namespace def {
    do_something();
    while (still_not_crashed()) {
        do_even_more();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
namespace abc {
namespace def {}
}
namespace abc {
namespace def { abc }
}
namespace abc {
namespace def { { } }
}
namespace abc {
namespace def { { abcd } }
}
namespace abc {
namespace def {
    abc
}
}
namespace abc {
namespace def { // some comment
    do_something();
}
}
namespace abc {
namespace def {
    do_something();
    while (still_not_crashed()) {
        do_even_more();
    }
}
```

Comment: I literally hit my head on my desk when i saw your answer. Thanks a lot. It works now.